# Angular 5 radio button not checked by default while setting ngModel for form

Tags: angular

**Working Case:**
In this case setting radio button checked is working fine

**Not working case**
but when i put ngModel then it is not working.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio5" id="radio4" class="css-checkbox" value="all" (click)="setSpecial(false)" [checked]="!isSpecial"  ngModel name="radioModel"/>
```

Comment: What not working? Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: give value to ngModel.. In your case it doesn't have any value

Answer (score 3):

You should have some value `assigned` to `ngModel`

If `selectedValue` value is `all` then the `radio button` will be `checked`.

**Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  selected = "all";

 }
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="radio" name="radio5" id="radio4" class="css-checkbox" value="all" [checked]="!isSpecial"[(ngModel)]="selected" name="radioModel"/> Radio1

<input type="radio" name="radio5" id="radio4" class="css-checkbox" value="notall" [checked]="!isSpecial"[(ngModel)]="selected" name="radioModel"/> Radio2
```

[**Here is a Working DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwwvpd)

Comment: @asheer qureshi, checked the DEMO, any help needed?

Comment: <input type="radio" name="radio5" id="radio4" class="css-checkbox" value="all" checked="true" name="radioModel"/> Radio1

Comment: for your above code, you need to take `checked="checked"`
<input type="radio" name="radio5" id="radio4" class="css-checkbox" value="all" checked="checked" name="radioModel"/> Radio1

Answer (score 2):

Ex:you do like this in your html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked [(ngModel)]="genderval"> Male<br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" [(ngModel)]="genderval"> Female<br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" [(ngModel)]="genderval"> Other
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in ts file constructor

```
this.genderval = 'male';
```